# OpenERP 7, warning gdata not updated when installing

Tags: gdata, odoo

I've installed OpenERP 7 on Ubuntu server 12.04.1 on a virtualbox 4.2.6. I followed [this useful tutorial](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/). But almost at the end, when I start the openerp server I get several lines of information on the log, including this one:

```
WARNING ? openerp.addons.google_docs.google_docs:
Please install latest gdata-python-client from
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list
```

At the end of step 6 of the tutorial the author points out that he had same warning. He then executed:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install gdata --upgrade
```

And the warning was gone. Not in my case. So after this action I manually downloaded the last version package and succesfully re-installed, but with same result, I’m still getting the warning message.

Any clue on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get python-gdata
```

Then:

```
wget http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/files/gdata-2.0.17.tar.gz
tar zxvf gdata-2.0.17.tar.gz
cd gdata-2.0.17/
python setup.py install
```

Comment: The *I manually downloaded the last version package and succesfully re-installed, but with same result* means precisely those actions suggested by you.

Comment: Fully re-installed from first step of the tutorial and directly applied the suggested solution, now it works.